# C++ primer 5 ed. mutual conversions

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I have some difficulty to understand mutual conversions, it is explained in C++ Primer 5 ed.:

> "In the following example, we’ve defined two ways to obtain an A from a B: either by using B’s conversion operator or by using the A constructor that takes a B:// usually a bad idea to have mutual conversions between two class types:

```
struct B;
struct A {
A() = default;
A(const B&);        // converts a B to an A
// other members
};

struct B {
    operator A() const; // also converts a B to an A
    // other members
};

A f(const A&);
B b;
A a = f(b); // error ambiguous: f(B::operator A())
        //          or f(A::A(const B&))
```

Because there are two ways to obtain an A from a B, the compiler doesn’t know which conversion to run; the call to f is ambiguous. This call can use the A constructor that takes a B, or it can use the B conversion operator that converts a B to an A. Because these two functions are equally good, the call is in error.

If we want to make this call, we have to explicitly call the conversion operator or the constructor:

```
A a1 = f(b.operator A()); // ok: use B's conversion operator 
A a2 = f(A(b));           // ok: use A's constructor
```

Note that we can’t resolve the ambiguity by using a cast—the cast itself would have
the same ambiguity."

- But when I defined the required members and `f` I don't get any error! his explanation looks so logical but I don't know why the code runs fine?!

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: `when I defined the required members and f I don't get any error` There is no ambiguity there, since the declarations spell out exactly what each means.

Comment: @Slava: It is said in the book that the call is ambiguous but when I run the code it works fine!

Comment: @dxiv: So do you think it is a bug in the book?

Comment: Compiler and its version, please. Clang 8 reports the ambiguity.

Comment: @S.M. I am using GCC.

Comment: I see question is on the end with bullet point, you created quite strange and confusing formatting

Comment: @Maestro No, what I was saying is that the ambiguity occurs (only) at the point where you call `f(b)`. I thought for a moment that you were wondering why you got no error when defining the classes.

Comment: I'm seeing the ambiguity.  Consider adding `explicit` in front of one or both of A's conversion constructor or B's conversion operator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But when I defined the required members and f I don't get any error!

The shown program is ill-formed for the reasons described in the book. If a compiler fails to issue a diagnostic message, then the compiler does not conform to the standard.

> I am using GCC.

You can ask GCC to try to conform to the C++ standard using the `-pedantic` option. Unfortunately, it will otherwise enable some language extensions by default.

Comment: Ok great! I tried the code on repl.it and got the warnings about ambiguity. Thank you so much! .